# Time of day Python

Tags: python, time

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'Hour'] >=6 & df.loc[i, 'Hour'] <= 12:
        df['time_of_day'] = "Morning"

    elif df.loc[i, 'Hour'] > 12 & df.loc[i, 'Hour'] <= 17:
        df['time_of_day'] == "Afternoon"
        
    elif df.loc[i, 'Hour'] > 17 & df.loc[i, 'Hour'] <= 22:
        df['time_of_day'] == "Evening"
    
    else:
        df['time_of_day'] = 'Night' 

df.time_of_day.value_counts()
```

Output:
Morning    1428
Name: time_of_day, dtype: int64

I try to create time_of_day column with for loop and if statement. Everything seems true, but it's not correctly working, the whole column is becoming "Morning".

Comment: Use `and` for boolean logic, `&` is a bit oberation. And it gets evalutated before compare operations (like +, -, ...), so you actually have `df.loc[i, 'Hour'] >= ( 6 & df.loc[i, 'Hour']) <= 12`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `df['time_of_day'] = "Morning"` , you are assigning "morning" to every value in that column. What you really want to do is apply your logic to each row separately. The smartest way to do this is with the `apply` method. All you need to do is define a function for your logic beforehand.

```
def determine_time(hour):

    if hour >=6 and hour <= 12:
        return "Morning"

    elif hour > 12 and hour <= 17:
        return "Afternoon"
        
    elif hour > 17 and hour <= 22:
        return "Evening"
    
    else:
        return 'Night' 

df['time_of_day'] = df['hour'].apply(determine_time)
```

Two more things, avoid using "&" as as it has a different meaning than `and` in Python. Lastly, `=` is for variable assignment but `==` checks if two things are equal (as in a Boolean expression)